# Mysql Select records from a table loop group by field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with products.
The table has a companyId field.
Let's describe it like this:

```
id --- companyId
 1   |    2     
 2   |    3     
 3   |    4     
 4   |    2     
 5   |    3     
 6   |    1
 7   |    4
```

I want to select all the records ordered by companyId but with the company id looping, as so:

```
id --- companyId
 6   |    1     
 1   |    2     
 2   |    3     
 3   |    4     
 4   |    2     
 5   |    3   
 7   |    4
```

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You have more than one company id. How it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using `MySQL user defined variables`

```
SELECT 
t.id,
t.companyId
FROM 
(
    SELECT
    *,
    IF(@sameCompany = companyId , @rn := @rn + 1,
        IF(@sameCompany := companyId, @rn := 1,@rn := 1)
    ) AS rn
    FROM companytable
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameCompany := -1, @rn := 1) AS var 
    ORDER BY companyId 
) AS t
ORDER BY t.rn , t.companyId
```

<kbd>[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e5968/1/0)</kbd>

---

**Explanation:**

First sort the data according to `companyId` so that the same company ids stick together.

Now take a walk along this sorted result and assign a sequentially increasing row number every time you see the same `companyId` otherwise assign `1` as `row number`.

Now name this sorted result (with row number) `t`.

Finally sort these data (`t`) according to ascending row number and ascending `companyId`.